# Why should I use thioacetamide instead of H2S when trying to separate cations from the H2S-group of cations?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I thought I shouldn't use $\ce{H2S}$ because of the smell/toxicity but was told there is a different reason. Does anyone know?

Comment: You may find these papers helpful: [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed032p474) and [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed032p258). However, thioacetamide is also a carcinogen and is known to induce acute or chronic liver disease.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{H2S}$ is a gas which is an ideal choice for carrying out qualitative analysis of cations in the beginning chemistry laboratory. It makes fine precipitates, easy to filtrate quantitatively. It has been used for decades in the previous century. But it has a disadvantage : its odor. Its odor of rotten eggs is painful and even unbearable. And the gas is also toxic. Its use is only possible if an important ventilation system is available in the lab, and if working in a hood. This is feasible in chemistry labs. But the problem is not solved for good. Because the gas is usually released on the roof of the building, and despite the high dilution factor, its odor may be perceptible by the neighbors in the next buildings. They are usually angry about the chemistry lab buildings of their neighborhood.

Thioacetamide gets slowly decomposed into $\ce{H2S}$ in the solution to be tested. Usually it is added to the solution to be tested in the minimum amount just necessary for the test. The odor is weak and bearable, even with awkward students.

As a difference, $\ce{H2S}$ is produced nearly continuously in a unique Kipp's apparatus installed in a hood where all students have to go for their analysis. Much $\ce{H2S}$ is lost during these experiments, and rejected in the outer atmosphere. This is why there is a tendency to replace $\ce{H2S}$ by thioacetamide in schools.

Comment: "H2S is a gas which is an ideal choice (...)" - not at all, being gaseous is itself a big complication.

Comment: @Mithoron. OK. Maybe it is not ideal. I should have said that it has the advantage of not adding any additional substance in the solution to be analyzed.